# Problem with windows title bar and activity bar

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweaks

I'm new to Linux. I'm using ubuntu 20.04. As you can see in the following picture

[image: picture]

I customize the dock and move it to the bottom. But the problem is, the windows title bar on top and the software menu/activity bar(the while section), both are taking separate spaces. But like Windows 10 I would like to merge them together so that they save some space. I searched and come with solutions like **pixel saver** and **unite**. But the problem is they both remove the windows title bar along with **maximize/minimize/close** buttons. But I need those buttons. Is there any way to remove the extra space of that title bar but also make the **maximize/minimize/close** button stay on top right along with the menu/activity bar of the software? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The extensions you discovered normally can preserve the window buttons in the top bar. The "Unite" extensions comes with quite some options. You may want to check these. I am not sure whether that works with the extension "Dash to Panel", which you use.

With respect to combining the menu bar with the window control buttons, that would require a special framework. The old Unity desktop had that, and it worked quite well with many common applications. Not sure if it would have worked with Visual Studio, though.

Currently, only the Unity desktop and the Mate desktop have that functionality. So if this is crucial to you, you could try one of these desktop environments. But as I indicated, even there, it will not work with every application.

Alternatively, you could try to live without the Window control buttons. Window management is also quickly done with shortcut keys:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close windows
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to normalize a window, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to maximize a window.
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to minimize a window.

Window controls can also be accessed after hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestion. I guess there is no way to do that!